# 2018 BMW S1000RR hesitates when hot

Tags: engine, motorcycle, bmw, hesitation

Recently got the bike serviced. Its done 5500 KMS. But soon after the 2nd service , I started experiencing engine hesitation issues , especially around 4 to 6000 rpm , regardless of gear. The engine stutters , almost feels like loss of power OR fuelling issues - The problem is especialy pronounced once the bike is properly HOT O in HOT condition i.e. during day time. I have also noticed , the mileage has come down a bit too. The dealer has cleaned the throttle body etc. checked on BMW diagnostics and they say , the bike is fine. But I know , its NOT fine. Any leads.

Comment: Hi and welcome.  What does "once the bike is properly HOT O in HOT condition"  mean? Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, this might be a fueling issue.

Can you check that your air filter is properly installed and clean and that nothing is blocking air from coming to the airbox ?

Has any modification been done to the bike ?